# How can I filter tables from list of tables according to specific word in their name and then combine all the filtered tables into one table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

I use this query to filter but I don't know how to combine all the filtered tables at once

```
SELECT table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%_exp%'
```

Comment: Try using [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it can help you in combining queries result.

Answer (score 0):

> then combine all the filtered tables into one table in sql?

You can use *select into*. In SQL Server, use *sys.tables*

```
SELECT schema_name(schema_id) SchemaName, [name] TableName
INTO <NewTable>
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_id = schema_id('dbo') and [name] LIKE '%_exp%';
/* specify the desired schema or remove to include all */
```